# How to type for optional known object properties?

Tags: typescript

Following throws “An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.” error.

```js
type MarkType = "partialBip39" | "validBip39"

interface MarkBadge {
  color: string
  label: string
  count: number
}

type MarkBadges = {
  [type: MarkType]: MarkBadge
}
```

Following solves issue, but both mark types are now mandatory object properties and, as a result, “Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'MarkBadges': partialBip39, validBip39” error is thrown.

```js
type MarkType = "partialBip39" | "validBip39"

interface MarkBadge {
  color: string
  label: string
  count: number
}

type MarkBadges = {
  [type in MarkType]: MarkBadge
}

let badges: MarkBadges = {}
```

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Mark it optional !

```
type MarkBadges = {
  [type in MarkType]?: MarkBadge
}

let badges: MarkBadges = {} // OK
```

Comment: OK… that was obvious, thanks!